# Powershell excel merge cells when cell could vary

Tags: excel, powershell, dynamic, merge, cells

I know how to merge cells, and this code works:

```
$MergeCells = $objWorksheet.Range("B1:C1") 

$MergeCells.Select()
$MergeCells.MergeCells = $true
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm doing this in a `ForEach` Server loop for IIS versions.  So whereas I'll always know the columns, I won't necessarily know the rows.  That number will vary.

Let's say it gets to the 5th server on the list `($x = 5)`, and those cells need to be merged.  I tried this:

```
$MergeCells = $objWorksheet.Range("B$x:C$x")
```

Thinking that the computer would know I meant

```
$MergeCells = $objWorksheet.Range("B5:C5")
```

But it did nothing.  No error, just nada.

I searched on here and Google, but in every post folks are merging cells where they know the column and rows are static.  As I said, my row will be dynamic.

Does anyone know how I can merge cells when my row number varies?  I've been able to use variables for cells in Excel just fine for other stuff.

Comment: I believe the issue maybe caused by the `:`. Does it work as `("B${X}:C${x}")` or `("B$($X):C$($x)")` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben!  The first one was the one I want.  The second option you gave, that does all the rows at once.  I may only need to do one row here or there. 

Oh and sorry for my little bit too laid back post.  Thanks for editing it.

Also, I meant to give you a upvote, but I erroneously did it on my own question.  I dont see where it lets me thank you and say answered other than me saying it here.  So thanks.   Oh wait, I see the triangle by your name, I clicked it.

Answer (score 3):

The `:` character when used in a variable name specifies the scope. So PowerShell is seeing `$x:C` as variable `C` in scope `x`.

By enclosing `x` in curly braces, then PowerShell will not look ahead in the string.

```
$MergeCells = $objWorksheet.Range("B${x}:C${x}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a formula problem, might be easier if you upload your sheet to Google sheets and use the add-ons feature and add Formula Helper. I'm using it myself. It looks for complicated formulas and helps you to solve it."

Comment: Thanks, Amanda.  I already know the formula, however, I cant paste that into Powershell as is, it gives me errors.  I needed help translating the formula to code powershell understands.  And just in case you are wondering I did not downvote your comment.